# Limits and 'L'Hopital' in higher dimensions.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be two $C^2$ functions with a critical point at $x_0$ and $f(x_0)=g(x_0)=0$ and $D(Df(x_0))=cD(Dg(x_0))\not= 0$, where $c$ is a constant. Show that $\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=c$.

Attempt: I tried using Taylor's theorem without much success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additional assumptions are necessary. Consider in ${\mathbb R}^2$ the example
$$f(x,y)=g(x,y):=x^2\ .$$
Then $D^2f(0,0)=D^2g(0,0)\ne0$ (as quadratic forms),
but the limit
$$\lim_{y\to0}{f(0,y)\over g(0,y)}$$
does not exist.

Therefore let's assume that $D^2f(0)=c\>D^2 g(0)$, where $H:=D^2 g(0)$ is *positive definite*. Then for $x=r\>u$, with $r>0$ and $\ |u|=1$, we have
$$f(x)=c\>{r^2\over2} H(u)+ o(r^2), \quad g(x)={r^2\over2} H(u)+ o(r^2)\qquad(r\to0)$$
and therefore
$${f(x)\over g(x)}=c{H(u)+o(1)\over H(u)+o(1)}\qquad(r\to0)\ .\tag{1}$$
Since $H(u)>0$ when $|u|=1$ this proves the claim.

Comment: I know that $\frac{o(r^n)}{|r|^n} \to 0$ as $r \to 0$. What does $o(1)$ notation mean?

Comment: @ironX: In $(1)$ the expression $o(1)$ means an error function depending on $r$ which converges to $0$ when divided by $1$, hence converges to $0$, when $r\to0$.